# Problems using Twitter4j on GAE throws 401 just after deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, twitter, twitter4j

Well, I'm having a weird error here:

I'm developing one GAE app to read some Twitter Data, and after read a lot of docs, I have it working on my test server (Running on my pc) but after deploy and test on the real (my appspot domain) it shows this message:

> 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or >incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the >system clock is in sync.
>   message - Could not authenticate you
>   code - 32

I've tried to recreate my OAuthAppToken and OAuthAppTokenSecret keys, even changing the permissions to "Write, Read and Direct Messages" and even assingning one Callback URL but nothing seems to work...

I've tried using **twitter4j.properties** OR using **setOAuthConsumer(TW_CONSUMER_KEY, TW_CONSUMER_SECRET)** OR a **ConfigurationBuilder** whith the correct constants and I'm experimenting the same Issue.

I'm working with AppEngine 1.8.3 and Twitter4j 3.0.4

Iv'e been writing on log and the Twitter object seems to be well created... I dont understand why is working on my PC but not on the real app.

On some other post someone says that could be because it needs to use Sync clock.. but he doesn't explains where to change that property...

Did someone had a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was me (and Twitter.... well..... I really think it was Twitter problem for being so dark on his api messages)...

On testing server I was looking for an existing account and on the cloud I was looking for an inexistent one. So, It was my mistake. But seriously, what about Twitter saying: "Access Forbidden"? That doesn't have any sense...